# Running Time Complexity of O (n / 2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I once understood this but not anymore. Lets say I have an algorithm that will return the number in the middle of an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  if (i == nums.length / 2) return nums[i];
}
```

The worst case of this will always be O (n / 2) right? There is no worse case than this. But how come we just conclude that it is O(n) ?

Comment: For `O(...)` purposes, constants don't matter. It's all about how the time *increases* as the number of elements gets larger, not about the absolute value of the time.

Comment: `2` is some constant factor, so `O(n/2)` can be reduced to `O(n)`. In other words , the complexity of looking at half the elements is no worse than looking at all the elements.

Comment: What bothers me is that O(n/2) is reduce to O(n). What if the code is written instead of `if (i == nums.length / 2) return nums[i];` we have `if (i == nums.length / 999999999) return nums[i];` then it is always going to be the first element. So (O(n / 99999999) is techinically O(1) ?

Comment: @Zanko no, O(n / 99999999) is still O(n), because there's no limit on n. If n=9999999999999999999999999 you can see that it still takes longer than if n=1.

Answer (score 10):

Big O time complexity is not about measuring the actual time an algorithm will take, it instead specifies what variables the time complexity is dependent on and what kind of relationship there is between those variables and the time complexity (ie linear, polynomial, exponential, etc).

Because constants do not effect the type of function the time complexity is they do not change the Big O value.

Note in your case the code you wrote may actually compile to something with constant time if the compiler is smart enough to note all iterations of the loop are dead but one.

Comment: Hello what if I have another algorithm that loops the whole array instead of half. So they are both O(n). But when people want to know which one is faster they are gonna say it is same speed but in actual fact the one that loop half away is twice as fast!

Comment: @Zanko That is true, however Big O is not the tool for that job. I dont know of another notation to describe exactly what you are looking for (not that that means it does not exist, just I dont know of it). I would just use some words to describe that one is twice as fast as the other

Comment: @Zanko knowing which algorithm is faster *isn't* what Big-O is useful for - it's for predicting how the algorithm reacts to different size input! It's not uncommon to find algorithms with higher `O()` that are faster on small `n`.

Comment: If you want to keep the constant, you can use [tilde notation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/). Not very common, however, although pioneered by Sedgewick and Wayne.