# What is the time complexity of the below program?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Program to reverse a string.I think it's complexity is O(n/2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxnr2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post pictures of code. Post code instead.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the loop takes n/2 steps. However, time complexity is still O(n).

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed O(n/2), which is the same as O(n), since constant factor doesn't matter in big O notation.

Note that in C this is not bounded by the loop but by the function strlen, which is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

It is actually O(n) as big o measures only "the big picture" -> the code depends only on the length of a string. More detailed answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250606/running-time-complexity-of-o-n-2)

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, every time you see that O(n/2) you need to convince yourself that is O(n)

[image]