# Reverse an array-run time

Tags: runtime, big-o

The following code reverses an array.What is its runtime ?

My heart says it is O(n/2), but my friend says O(n). which is correct? please answer with reason. thank you so much.

```
void reverse(int[] array) {
    for (inti = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        int other = array.length - i - 1;
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[other];
        array[other] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 is a constant factor in O(n/2), therefore since constants doesn't matter in time complexity, the time complexity is O(n). Refer to [Running Time Complexity of O (n / 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250606/running-time-complexity-of-o-n-2)

Comment: so if i have like this in for loop, i < array.length;  then it is also O(N) right?

Comment: Yes, @Vijay . SInce constants doesn't matter in time complexity

Comment: then we can't differentiate to my friend that which algorithm run faster. isn't it?

Comment: Runtime could mean as the user is sending the input. So, you could take it char by char but the issue is going to be length. Is there a max length defined?

Comment: yes it is a character array

Comment: here the "n" is array length. Generally big Oh ( O) notation represents the worst case complexity of algorithm ( others are best, average). And worst case complexity, is : O(n)

Comment: @MuraliD oh okay. But even though it is for worst case, it divides the run time to half EVERYTIME right. so it should be O(n/2). isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Big-O complexity captures how the run-time scales with n as n gets arbitrarily large. It isn't a direct measure of performance. f(n) = 1000n and f(n) = n/128 + 10^100 are both O(n) because they both scale linearly with n even though the first scales much more quickly than the second, and the second is actually prohibitively slow for all *n* because of the large constant cost. Nonetheless, they have the same complexity class. For these sorts of reasons, if you want to differentiate actual performance between algorithms or define the performance of any particular algorithm (rather than how performance scales with n) asymptotic complexity is not the best tool. If you want to measure performance, you can count the exact number of operations performed by the algorithm, or better yet, provide a representative set of inputs and just measure the execution time on those inputs.

As for the particular problem, yes, the for loop runs n/2 times, but you also do some constant number of operations, `c`, in each of those loops (subtractions, array accesses, variable assignments, conditional check on i). Maybe `c=10`, it's not really important to count precisely to determine the complexity class, just to know that it's constant. The run-time is then `f(n)=c*n/2`, which is O(n): the fact that you only do n/2 for-loops doesn't change the complexity class.